# How to setup internet television using Linux box with DNS name?

Tags: linux, iptv

I've got:

- Linux box with public DNS name
- apache
- web development skills
- tons of video files to broadcast

I want to create simple web page, which contains some plugin that shows my files to whoever wants to see them on the web. What free tools should I use (server streaming side and HTML side)? If I am asking in a wrong place, where should I go?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at a few of the open source video players like [JW player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/), [OSFLV](http://www.osflv.com/), [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/), etc. They might give you some ideas.

Comment: not really that helpful. also, if you're going to suggest software, *always* include the links to them.

Comment: Those are open source video players. I also added links to save you the trouble of visiting Google.